# Child views not added horizontally in adding FlowLayout programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an Android app. In my add, I am adding FlowLayout with child views to a linear layout. I am adding programmatically. But when I add FlowLayout with children, its children are added vertically.

This installed flow layout from this link using grande:

```
https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout/blob/develop/README.md
```

This is how I add flow layout with child views:

```
FlowLayout attrControlsSubContainer = new FlowLayout(getBaseContext());
                                    FlowLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new FlowLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                    attrControlsSubContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                                    for(int i=0;i<attrs.length();i++)
                                    {
                                        CheckBox chkAttribute = new CheckBox(getBaseContext());
                                        chkAttribute.setText(attrs.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                                        chkAttribute.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                        chkAttribute.setId(attrs.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"));
                                        attrControlsSubContainer.addView(chkAttribute);
                                    }
                                    attributeControlContainer.addView(attrControlsSubContainer);
```

//attribute control container is the linear layout

This is the XML layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/attribute_added_control_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>
```

When I add as I explained. It is added vertically. What I want is horizontal.

This is the screenshot:

[image]

How can I achieve it?

Comment: at which point in code did you asked for layout to be added horizontally?

Comment: I want checkboxes added horizontally to flowlayout that I added programmatically.

Comment: Set `FlowLayout.LayoutParams` with `WRAP_CONTENT` for the width on each `CheckBox`.